# Having a div grid in CSS/HTML correspond to a 2D array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently doing a personal project where I'm trying to create a grid of divs in HTML that correspond to a 2D array in Javascript, but I'm not really certain of the best way to do this.

What I'm trying to do more specifically is whenever a div in the grid is clicked, it should change color and change a number in the array from 0 to 1 (or vice versa). There are other numbers as well, but that is the basic form of it.

I'm assuming using some sort of onClick listener to change the class of the div would be the best way to handle the color, but how can I link the array to the grid?

Thanks for any help you can give guys.

Comment: Could you provide more information on how the values stored in this 2D array?

Comment: The values are going to be stored as an array of arrays, as such:
var x = new Array(25);
for (var i=0;i<25;i++){
  x[i] = new Array(25);
}

Comment: So, each position of the first array will correspond to a new array, right? What's the order that you are rendering those divs?

Comment: I'm rendering the divs one row at a time from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing to match elements in DOM to elements in array

```js
var data =[
  {color:'yellow', num:0},
  {color:'orange',  num:0}
];

$(function(){
  var $divs =  $('.some-class').click(function(){
     var divIndex = $divs.index(this);
     $(this).css('backgroundColor', data[divIndex].color);
     data[divIndex].num ++;
     console.log(data);
  });
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">Click me - item #1</div>
<div class="some-class">Click me - item #2</div>
```